# PHP sending data to the redirected page

Tags: php, html, redirect, database-connection

I am building a small website for viewing and amending data entries in a database.

I have a form where a user can select the table they want to view in a drop down select.

On submit I call a php script which handles pulling the data and then redirects to the .html site on which I want to display the results.

I know that my script works in that if I do not use the header redirect the correct results are printed.

I am wondering how I can access the data from the website I'm redirecting to so that I could display them. 
 I would welcome any alternative suggestions.

Comment: you cannot send db data from page to page.try echoing the data in hml in the same page without calling redirect

Answer (score 0):

The .html implies static data, are the tables always static or are you loading from a data source (mysql, etc)?  If you're just trying to load a static HTML page from a drop down, then maybe you should just use javascript?

http://webdesign.about.com/od/javascript/f/blfaqddredirect.htm

Unless I am mistaken on what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Hi! Sadly the data isn't static. I am pulling entries from a database and want to populate a table on a _different_ page with the results.

Comment: Then you are not wanting to direct to an .html page.  You just want to display the HTML through PHP.  You can accomplish this in many ways.  By using a PHTML format, using PHP echoes, or using an <<< END reference.